# PHPExcel format different from excel version

Tags: php, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I have a big problem with new Excel on Windows 8.
I generate some xls file with PHPExcel and set some format to cells like this:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Alessandro Minoccheri")
                                 ->setLastModifiedBy("Alessandro Minoccheri")
                                 ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                 ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                 ->setDescription("Generazione report inverter")
                                 ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                                 ->setCategory("");
$row_style = array(
      'fill' => array(
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
      ),
      'borders' => array(
            'allborders' => array(
                 'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
            )
       )
);

for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
       /*insert value in column
       ------
       */
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$i.':M'.$i)->applyFromArray( $row_style );
}
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('test.xls');
```

In my OpenOffice or in old Excel version(2007) on Windows 7 all cells are ok.

On Windows 8 with new Excel I see some rows with the style others without style! But the style is applied!

There isn't error in script I have insert:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

But no error return.
I print all rows with the same method but I don't know that the same file is different from Excel versions.

Can someone know how can I do to fix it in new Excel?

Thanks

Comment: In your for it miss a $. You write i<=10

Comment: error of copy and paste isn't that the problem @Kvasir

Comment: I don't understand why you put getStyle('A'.$i.':M'.$i) and not just getStyle('A'.$i) ... sorry my mistake misunderstand what you wanted to do.

Comment: Because I set all style to all column of the row

Comment: What is the extention of your file generat .xslx or .xsl?

Comment: What version of `phpexcel` are you using? Maybe the new Excel has some different parsing methods. (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/changelog.txt)